# Splitting array of objects in to multiple arrays by certain criteria

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft

```
import * from dw::core::Arrays
var divideNr = 3
var payload = [1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3]

fun splitting (array1) = 
    if ((array1 splitAt divideNr).l[divideNr-1] == 2) 
        array1 splitAt divideNr
    else 
    array1 splitAt  divideNr-1

output application/json
---
splitting(payload)
```

So I am trying to divide the the array in to multiple arrays of max size three. The idea is that I cant have 1 and 2 in two seperate arrays. With splitAt I cut it in to two parts (left and right). Left is correct, but right one is array of remaining objects. I cant figure out how to continue iterating over remaining ones so in the end I get an array of arrays (with max amount if 3 objects and 1 followed by 2 not split in to two seperate arrays). In my real example there are way more different objects so I cant cut them at the same place every time.

Answer (score 0):

Use [divideBy()](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.1/dw-arrays-functions-divideby) instead of splitAt():

```js
import * from dw::core::Arrays
var divideNr = 3
var payload = [1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3]
output application/json
---
payload divideBy divideNr
```

Output:

```json
[[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]
```

Note that your approach is not needed because there is a built-in function that achieves that. Having said that, to make it work you should modify your function to be a recursive function, applied to the remaining items.

Comment: As I said its not always the same. This would not work if it was var payload = [1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3]. But I need solution for a payload like this.

Comment: What is that doesn't work with divideBy() for that payload? You should also share the expected output for each input, so it is clearer if a solution matches the expected output.

Comment: [[1,2,3],[4,5],[1,2,3],[4,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,1,2],[3]]

Comment: Why the second element of the output is of size 2? the question seems to mention divide every 3 items, then the remainders at the end.

Comment: Because as I stated - 1 followed by 2 cant be divided in to two arrays. They must stay in the same array. If it wasnt for this I wouldnt be asking this.

Comment: Kindly add the information from the comments to the question so it is more clear.

Comment: What if 1 is not followed by 2. for example `[3,4,1,5,2]` should the result be `[[3,4],[1,5,2]]` or `[[3,4,1],[5,2]]`

Comment: @HarshankBansal Yes, as long as they are in the same array (1 and 2 that follows) all is fine.

Comment: I did not get it. Which of the two will be the result in the case I mentioned above? In the second one 1 and 2 are in different arrays.